# How to get the base URL of an external website

Tags: php, url

I'm using cURL to return data from external sites. How can I return the base URL of a site with PHP?

For example, I have this URL:
`http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Insignia%26%23153%3B+-+55%22+Class+/+1080p+/+120Hz+/+LCD+HDTV/2009148.p?id=1218317000232&skuId=2009148`

I just want `http://www.bestbuy.com`

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Insignia%26%23153%3B+-+55%22+Class+/+1080p+/+120Hz+/+LCD+HDTV/2009148.p?id=1218317000232&skuId=2009148";
echo "";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

//Would give you
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.bestbuy.com
    [path] => /site/Insignia%26%23153%3B+-+55%22+Class+/+1080p+/+120Hz+/+LCD+HDTV/2009148.p
    [query] => id=1218317000232&skuId=2009148
)

Answer (score 2):

use parse_url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

REGEX :)

use this one (not sure if it will work on php but you can modify it slightly if needed)

`/^((?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:.+?))(?:\s*$|\/.*$)/`

so this will optionally match http:// or https:// (? sign after `\/\/)` ) then will lazy match until either end of line or `/` if exists

and your desired url is in the first capture group

optionally you can omit ?: everywhere in the regex and you can get

- first: full url
- second: params
- third: protocol
- fourth: domain